# How to debug C++ python extension?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, debugging, gdb

I want to debug my C++ python extension library. Currently the library is throwing an exception and to figure out where, I want to use *gdb*. The problem is that *gdb* is not catching the exception stack. I did as following:

```
$ gdb python3
(gdb) run script.py
UserWarning: An exception occurred: sort_index(): detected NaN
```

And when I try to use `backtrace`:

```
(gdb) backtrace
No stack.
```

I know that such backtrace is possible because I already did that before, probably I am missing something. The library is being compiled with debug mode.

Comment: This is generally correct, Are you debugging the debug build of the module? Is it on the pythonpath? Do you get the same error from running "python3 script.py" on the command line?

Comment: It seems that your process has exited before you ask for the backtrace.  Was a **C++** exception ever thrown (and perhaps then converted into a Python exception)?

Comment: @DavisHerring yes I was passing C++ exception to python and now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A Python exception will not cause GDB to stop—it knows only to stop on *signals*, not “normal”, private error handling.  It might be possible to set a breakpoint on the Python functions that set the Python error indicator, but they might be inlined (or be macros).

Conveniently, you *can* set a “breakpoint” on the magic function that throws **C++** exceptions—it’s called a **catchpoint** and is set with the odd-looking `catch throw`.  (This will be very noisy if (caught) exceptions are more common than they ought to be in your code!)

Finally, note that you can’t ever let a C++ exception **escape** into Python—even to catch it in yet a larger C++ context, because Python doesn’t know how to clean up in that circumstance.